# Changing MVC Razor Img src with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is a MVC application. I have a IEnumberable(Of T) viewmodel that is passed in to the partial view. There will be a next and prev. image button on the lower part of the page. The Idea is simple. When the user clicks the Next Button it shows the next image and when they click the prev. button it shows the previous image. I have started working on the below javascript to achieve this. However as I am totally new to javascript I feel that I am missing something here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = 0;
      function PreviousImage() {
         c -= 1;
         if (!c < 0) {
           ('@m')=c
           document.getElementById("photoBox").src = ('@Url.Content(String.Format("~/PropertyImages/{0}/{1}", Model(m).PropertyImageFolder, Model(m).PhotoName))')

         }
}
```

the div container for the image and the buttons is as follows:

```
<div>
   <img src="" id="photoBox" />
   <input type="button" id="NextImage" value="Next Image" /><input type="button" id="PrevImage" value="Previous Image" onclick="PreviousImage()" />
</div>
```

`m` is just a vb local variable in the view that gets set when c is incremented. So that I can get the model item by index.

Any suggestions? Am I on the right Track? Or is this a total fail of an attempt at what I am after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to first build all the images on the page with the `display style` set to `none` then i change it through javascript. Below is my solution for this.

```
<div>
  @For i As Integer = 0 To Model.Count - 1
    Dim y As String = String.Format("image{0}", i)
    @<div id="@y" style="display:none"><img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/PropertyImages/{0}/{1}", Model(i).PropertyImageFolder, Model(i).PhotoName))" height="200" width="200"/></div>
  Next
<div> <input type="button" id="NextImage" value="Next Image" onclick="ImageNext()" /><input type="button" id="PrevImage" value="Previous Image" onclick="ImagePrev()" /></div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
  var c = 0;
  //var currImage = 0;
  var ImageCount = ('@Model.Count');
  function ImageNext() {
   c += 1;
    if (c <= ImageCount-1 && c >= 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < ImageCount; i++) {
            document.getElementById("image" + i).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("image" + c).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        c = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < ImageCount; i++) {
            document.getElementById("image" + i).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("image" + c).style.display = "block";

    }
 }
 function ImagePrev() {
    c -= 1;
    if (c <= ImageCount - 1 && c >= 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < ImageCount; i++) {
            document.getElementById("image" + i).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("image" + c).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        c = ImageCount - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < ImageCount; i++) {
            document.getElementById("image" + i).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("image" + c).style.display = "block";

    }
  }
</script>
```

By doing it this way your partial view does not need to reload.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a hidden field control for storing and retrieving the index value instead of vb local variable.

Please refer the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hiddenfld=document.getElementById("m");
    var c = hiddenfld.value;
      Function Previous Image () {
         c -= 1;
         if (!c < 0) {
           hiddenfld.value=c
           document.getElementById("photoBox").src = ('@Url.Content(String.Format("~/PropertyImages/{0}/{1}", Model(c).PropertyImageFolder, Model(c).PhotoName))')

         }
</script>
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: a hiddenfield seems like a great idea for times when its not going to be a model that contains 1 too many indexes in it.

Comment: you can try by passing single image object instead of passing Ienumerable list. The next and previous button need to move outside of partial view. On every button click you can reload the partial view by passing the ImageItem of the Ienumerable list.